# Firebase email link authentication leads to a page that says "Error encountered" - "The selected page mode is invalid"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am on localhost with Firebase auth (firebase v7.23.0). The email is sent okay. I click the sign in link from my email. I get this error page on my <PROJECT>.firebaseapp.com

[image: !]

My code is mostly below, but this all works. It's the Firebase page is giving an error. I am not sure what else I need to set up. localhost is on the allowed domains. The error is on the Firebase side so I cannot do much to debug or fix it.

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
  // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
  // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
  // url: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}/`,
  url: http://localhost:7000/#postLogin,
  // This must be true.
  handleCodeInApp: true
};

firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(this.email, actionCodeSettings)
        .then(() => {
          // The link was successfully sent. Inform the user.
          // Save the email locally so you don't need to ask the user for it again.
          window.localStorage.setItem('email', this.email);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // Some error occurred, you can inspect the code: error.code
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure how you managed to get this url. Either you removed apiKey from your url to attach screenshot on SO or you have misconfigured something due to which apiKey is not included in the email verification link.

To test my hypothesis, I created new firebase app and deployed it to https://test-auth-79dae.firebaseapp.com/ which just has a send email link button, which sends email to myself and email link works if I click on verification link received in email. **It only doesn't work if I remove apiKey from the link in the email**.

[image]

Your email link should be:

`https://test-auth-79dae.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey={yourApiKey}&oobCode={obbCode}&continueUrl={urlParameter}&lang=en`

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, the API is not passed in for some reason. I do have it configured with initializeApp and everything else works. `firebase.initializeApp({apiKey: 'abc123'})`. I will check to see why the API key doesn't show up in the URL in the email.

Comment: Check you email template may be you will find something there.

Comment: I haven't had time to take a look, but the missing API key in the URL is a 100% lead. There was another answer with a promising lead (hashtag in the URL). I'm going to award bounty to this one for now. Thank you!

Comment: @ngokevin I actually tried with hash tag in url in the email and it's not an issue, fyi.

Answer (score 6):

Removing and readding the provider block fixed the issue for me aside from that no matter what I tried , it did not work.

[image]

going to firebase -> authenthentication -> sign in methods -> delete provider
Then readd provider

Answer (score 3):

When user click on email link, they will land on a page. let's say `/register/complete`.

So you should have the following code for this to work:

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
  url: `http://localhost:3000/register/complete,
  handleCodeInApp: true
};
```

Your problem might be in this url that you have:

```
url: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}/`,
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried hardcoding the URL and still have the issue. Hardcoded or not, the continueUrl in the signIn link is the same: "...continueUrl=http://localhost:7000/%23loginPost..."

Comment: You should not have % in your url. I see you have two `//`. remove one `/` and it should work. Make sure not extra characters or empty space in url.

Answer (score 2):

In a freshly created firebase project, you may need some time to get the API key sent in email verification. Just wait few hours to get the key

Comment: Exactly what I went through, too

Answer (score 1):

This one the bug from firebase simple way to do is delete authenticator provider(Like email/password phone all those) and re-add the authenticator provider (Email/Password) by this firebase automically creates the apikey. And what actually happened to me was first time when I created the authenticator provider (Email/Password) the firebase was not able to create the API Key. Hence solution is:

Delete the authenticator provider (Email/Password) and re-add/enable it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be solved it was an issue on Firebase's end. I had the same issue and through their contact support they assured me that it was on their end.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when the parameter of `link` was returned from server not url-encoded.

So that this link was giving the error:

```
https://link.mydomain.com.ua/?link=https://mydomain.com.ua/__/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=blablabla&apiKey=blablabla&continueUrl=...
```

While it worked when converted into this:

```
https://link.mydomain.com.ua/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com.ua%2F__%2Fauth%2Faction%3Fmode%3DverifyEmail%26oobCode%3Dblablabla%26apiKey%3Dblablabla%26continueUrl%3D...
```

Comment: Well, how did you do it? I'm using the Firebase SDK for Swift and I don't have any clue on how to get, let alone, url encode the `?link=` parameter

Comment: @Throvn In my case the link was generated by backend engineers, so I asked them to url-encode it. If you generate the link on iOS, I suppose you may use `.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)`

Answer (score 0):

For those who struggle with these details and are using `sendEmailVerification`, I followed these steps:

1. Go to the Firebase project settings.
2. Add an application at the bottom (in my case, it was a web app).
3. Make sure that the application was successfully created, then reload the page (I had to do this twice).
4. Under "Organization", you will find your API key right after "Web API Key" (I had to reload the page to see it).

And there you go!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to enable this option to get the api key if you will use web app [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ8ap.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that when I created the Firebase Project it didn't automatically select a GCP resource location and I think because of this, even if I enabled Authentication, the project didn't generate a Web API key for me.

So I went to the Firebase Project Settings and selected a "Default GCP resource location". After that refreshed the page once and the Web API key appeared.

edit: Although, I've later seen in an older video that someone already had an Web API key generated, even though above it, the Default GCP resource location was still "Not yet selected". So maybe this is not the case for everyone, but I've tried every solution from this page and only after doing this did I get the Web API key.