# Error encountered The selected page mode is invalid - Flutter Firebase email verification link does not contain the api key

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to implement the email verification functionality into my Flutter app. All is good, the verification email is sent to the provided email address, but the link provided in the email does not contain the API key. When the link is clicked, it redirects to a webpage saying: **Error encountered** *The selected page mode is invalid.*

Here's an example link that I got: https://fir-test-b41e2.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=PGEydFP0x64TYJIYU9_1mv5wR6xxW6mfMlLWF3v3fXIAAAGNgpPsyA&apiKey=&lang=en. As you can see the `apiKey=` is empty but if I copy the link to the browser and insert the API key from the `firebase_options.dart` file, then it works fine and the email is verified.

Comment: I'm not sure how this happens, but my guess is that your API got lost/misplaced. For some users it seems to be fixed if they disable the provider and reenabled it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77802763/209103

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I had modified the email template, and a dialog for reset template appeared at the top. So, i clicked on it and reset the template, after that it worked perfectly.